# How to convert data frame with colors to a character list in r

Tags: r, dataframe, colors, character

I have a data frame that contains color codes for different actors (two variables: var1 = "actor" and var2 = "color"). I would like to turn this data frame into a character list that entails the color code for each actor. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Sample data frame:

```
actor <- c('CDU','SPD','Greens', 'FDP')
color <- c('#000000', '#FF0000', '#009500', '#FFFF00')
df <- data.frame(actor, color)

df
```

|  | actor | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CDU | #000000 |
| 2 | SPD | #FF0000 |
| 3 | Greens | #009500 |
| 4 | FDP | #FFFF00 |

What I want is a character list I can create manually like this:

```
actor_color <- c('CDU' = '#000000',
             'SPD' = '#FF0000',
             'Greens'= '#009500',
             'FDP' = '#FFFF00')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `setNames` function to apply the names to your list of colors as below:

```
l <- setNames(df$color, df$actor)
> print(l)
      CDU       SPD    Greens       FDP 
"#000000" "#FF0000" "#009500" "#FFFF00"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is all I wanted :)